# Add subsequent values in pandas dataframe based on True/False "sets"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'num' : [0.43, 5.2, 1.3, 0.33, .74, .5, .2, .12],
                   'complete' : [False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True]
                    })

df


   complete num
0   False   0.43
1   True    5.20
2   False   1.30
3   False   0.33
4   True    0.74
5   False   0.50
6   True    0.20
7   True    0.12
```

I would like to create a list of sums, with one value for every `True` entry followed by at least one `False` in `df.complete`.  It should be the sum of the `True` num, plus every `False` num after, until the next `True` occurs again.

In this example it would be a list of two sums:

```
[(5.2 + 1.3 + 0.33), (0.74 + 0.5)]
```

So the final result would be

```
[6.83, 1.24]
```

What is a pythonic way to produce the final list?

Comment: What would be the output if there was another `True 0.5` line between line 3 and 4? Should the output ignore it (no `False` value following) or should it just include the value 0.5 in the final list?

Comment: The output should ignore a `True` with no `False` following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
# create a group
df['group'] = df['complete'].cumsum()

# find which groups to add
vals = df.group.value_counts()
groups_to_consider = vals[vals > 1].index.tolist()

## add values
df[df['group'].isin(groups_to_consider)].groupby('group')['num'].sum().tolist()

# [6.83, 1.24]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very clever and helpful!  Even though I didn't specify that True values alone should not have a sum earlier, I've now edited the question.

Comment: @jua-kali updated the answer. let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for the update. I just want to make a note that your original answer was `df['group'] = df['complete'].cumsum()` then `df.groupby('group')['num'].sum()[1:].tolist()`. It works when every `True` needs a sum and this has helped me with another problem.  I just wanted it to be here in case I need to refer back to this question in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can also do

```
df.groupby(df[df.complete.cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)].complete.cumsum()).num.sum()
```

---

Explanation:

```
df.complete.cumsum()
```

gives you a `Series` where you will want the rows with same numbers (e.g. 1 1 1 and 2 2) summed.

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    4
```

Then, `duplicated(keep=False)` allows you to filter your `df` with only rows that this happen.

```
df[df.complete.cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)]

    complete    num
1   True        5.20
2   False       1.30
3   False       0.33
4   True        0.74
5   False       0.50
```

Now just use `.cumsum()` again and groupby with it this *filtered data frame*

```
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2

df.groupby(...).num.sum()


1.0    6.83
2.0    1.24
```

---

Edit:

```
c = df.complete.cumsum()
d = c[c!=0].duplicated(keep=False)
e = df.loc[df.index.isin(d[d].index)].complete.cumsum()
df[df.index.isin(e.index)].groupby(e).num.sum()
```

This works for every case I believe :)

Comment: Clever. But would include the first value if the df starts with several False values.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be the following:

```
In [28]: df.groupby(df.complete.cumsum()).sum()[1:].num.values
Out[28]: array([ 6.83,  1.24])
```

Comment: This would ignore the first group even if the df starts with a True. Also, see the OP's answer to my question in the comments.